# Finding Websites From Company Name

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've got a list of 6,000 company names (along with their headquarters address) and I need to find the web address for each of them. I'm considering using the Google Web API (obviously this will take a few days as only 1,000 queries per day are allowed) to do this(search for "COMPANY_NAME CITY STATE") and then take the first result. However I'm not 100% sure this will work, and I feel like there's a better way. I can do this in any language I know really, C++, Java, PHP, Python. This only has to be run once.

How would I use WHOIS to do this? I know how I would do it if I already knew the URL, but not the other way around(name to URL). And what would I do if it were privately registered?

BTW, these are US businesses.

Comment: not really a strategy, but WHOIS'ing the domain and checking the registered entity and address is a good sanity check.

Comment: Any particular locality for companies e.g. US, UK - or global?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WHOIS instead of Google API for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Amazons Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/). It's perfect for these kinds of tasks which can be hard to automate and typically need a person to validate them. It will cost a little but it should be manageable, depending on how bad you want the results.

Comment: ...mturk can be used only if you provide US address when registering, btw.